# Python : get the next working time slot

Tags: python, datetime, time

Handling a staff planning (Python 2.7), I have for a given person a list of working days (and times) in [isoWeek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

With a given date I'm trying to determine when will be the next date the staff person will be available.

```
working_days = {
    1:
    {
        'start': datetime.time(8, 0),
        'end': datetime.time(17, 15)
    },
    2:
    {
        'start': datetime.time(7, 45),
        'end': datetime.time(17, 0)
    },
    3:
    {
        'start': datetime.time(8, 0),
        'end': datetime.time(16, 45)
    },
    4:
    {
        'start': datetime.time(10, 0),
        'end': datetime.time(15, 30)
    },
    5:
    {
        'start': datetime.time(8, 30),
        'end': datetime.time(17, 15)
    }
}

searched_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 13, 20, 57, 00) // Wednesday
searched_date_week_day = searched_date.isoweekday()
```

> expected result : datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 14, 10, 00, 00) // Thursday at 10

I would have liked to just use the weekdays to achieve this result but I have my doubts on it.

What I wrote is tricked on the simplest example (my searched time is greater than the end working time of the staff)

```
next_working_day = next((x for x in working_days if x >= searched_date_week_day), None)
```

> gives: 3 , Wednesday

Considering there will me more tricky cases (let's imagine my searched date is on a Sunday, isoweek 7, it doesn't work), is my only way out is to transform my working_days in some `datetime.datetime` list?

[Fiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c95cbf8c-aad8-4557-a179-2845a20d50be/?i=true)

Comment: Have you checked that Python is preserving your keys in the order you define them?

Comment: Well that's an excellent point. It does so far but it must be just a matter of luck! Thanks for pointing that

Comment: I am musing on the idea of suggesting changing working `working_days` to a list and using `(searched_date_week_day + 1) % len(working_days)` as your 'iterator'. What do you think? You'd need to change how you find the current entry, but it might work.

Comment: @Nick , not sure I understood correctly but I created the Fiddle with the suggested change https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/742347b6-04a0-49cc-b7f4-296dd358ec9d/?i=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your Fiddle as a starting point:

```
import datetime

working_days = [{'start': datetime.time(8, 0), 'end': datetime.time(17, 0), 'day': 1}, {'start': datetime.time(8, 0), 'end': datetime.time(17, 0), 'day': 2}, {'start': datetime.time(8, 0), 'end': datetime.time(17, 0), 'day': 3}, {'start': datetime.time(8, 0), 'end': datetime.time(17, 0), 'day': 4}]


searched_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 13, 20, 57, 00)
searched_date_week_day = searched_date.isoweekday()

i = 0

while i < len(working_days) and working_days[i]['day'] < searched_date_week_day:
    i = i + 1

# if reached the end then next working day must be first day of next week
if i == len(working_days):
    next_working_day = working_days[0]
else:
    next_working_day = working_days[(i+1) % len(working_days)]
print next_working_day
```

It assumes that the entries in your list are in day order.

Comment: This is excellent. I tweaked it a little bit and it fully answers to my problem: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/976ab1d6-5379-4c52-8152-af21252f24a2/?i=true